# MySQL - ORDER BY CASE WHEN doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, search, sql-order-by, case

I have a table 'users' with two columns (id,full_name) i created a search box using PHP after that i searched how to make it order by relevance i found the solution but it's not working correctly so if there is three lines containing John Smith in full name then it gives me only one result here is the table

```
 id  |   full_name
 1   |   John Smith
 2   |   John Smith
 3   |   John Smith
```

And Here is my code

```
$find = $_GET['q'];
$values=explode(" ", $find);
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE";
$i=0;
foreach($values as $v)
{
$v=trim($v);
if($i==0)
{
$sql.=" full_name LIKE '%$v%'";
}
else
{
$sql.=" OR full_name LIKE '%$v%'";
}

$i++;
}
$sql.="GROUP BY full_name ORDER BY CASE WHEN full_name like '$find %' THEN 0
           WHEN full_name like '$find%' THEN 1
           WHEN full_name like '% $find%' THEN 2
           ELSE 3
      END, full_name";
$query3 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)) {
echo $row3['full_name']."<br/>";
}
```

So my problem is that when i search for John it gives me only one result which is **John Smith** while i want it to give me

- **John Smith**
- **John Smith**
- **John Smith**

I would appreciate any help

Comment: oke now you are changing your code change the extension you use too. As the mysql_* are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and deleted from PHP 7.0 use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. And also your code is open to SQL-injections use [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/5396496) when handling user input. please do this otherwise you're gonna regret it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice i'll do it right now in my whole website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `GROUP BY full_name` it is grouping the `John Smith` names together.

Comment: Thank you very much you saved my day <3,Pfff this rules it says you need 4 minutes to accept an answer